# Can't change fancyBox 3 data attribute

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm looking to change a fancybox item's data attribute with this line of code. I'm using fancyBox 3. For some reason it won't let me change the data attribute. I've checked the selector which responds on i.e. `hide()`.

```
$("#line-up .interactive .btns .btn").click(function(e){

    // If has not class active
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active"))
    {
        // Filter
        e.preventDefault();
        $target = $(this).data("id");
        $("#line-up .interactive .btns .btn").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // Select the items and do action
        $("#line-up .artists .item").removeClass("active");
        $("#line-up .artists .item[data-id=" + $target + "]").addClass("active");

        // Change fancybox data
        $("#line-up .artists .item.active .artist").data("fancybox", "single");

    } else {

        // Reset
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $("#line-up .artists .item").addClass("active");

        // Change fancybox data
        $("#line-up .artists .item .artist").data("fancybox", "gallery");
    }
})
```

Would be awesome if someone could help

Comment: could you post the html where you use the `data` attribute?

Comment: have you done a console .log on the data attribute - by using data, it changes it in memory rather than on the actual html itself - so you won't see the changes if you inspect element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `data-fancybox` attribute using `attr()` method, e.g, `.attr("data-fancybox", "gallery")`

Comment: Thanks <3 Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#line-up .artists .item .artist")
    .data("fancybox", "gallery")
    .attr('data-fancybox', 'gallery');
```

as [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323388/cant-change-fancybox-3-data-attribute#comment85648582_49323388) said, `.data` only won't change your html, but `.attr` will

tell me how it goes

Comment: I thought I could set data attributes as well with this function, but little did I know ;). Thanks for your response, worked like a charm!